# This specific PHP function is taking 15 seconds to calculate. What part of it is causing the lag?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I know this may look very specific but I'm new to PDO database connections and I had to rewrite this component. I used Php microtime to check what part of my code was slow to load and it narrowed down to the function below (called from a class file). Can you help me figure out what is the inefficient part of this code? The rest of my functions use PDO as well and some also look at joined tables without any performance issues.

```
   public function GetRecentActivity($user = null, $length = 20){
    global $pdo;

    if($user==null){
        $user = ((isset($_SESSION['UserID']))?$_SESSION['UserID']:FALSE);
        }
    if($user==FALSE){
        return -1;
        }

    $actions = array();

    $courses = $pdo->prepare("SELECT courses.courseID, courses.courseName FROM courses INNER JOIN courseRoles on courses.courseID = courseRoles.courseID WHERE courseRoles.userRole != 'Blocked' AND courseRoles.userID = :user");
    if(!$courses->execute(array(':user'=>$user)))
        return -1;
    // now we have an array of [courseID, courseName]
    //prepare some statements for the big loop
    $discs = $pdo->prepare("SELECT dID, dTitle, courseDiscussions.courseDiscussionTime FROM discussions INNER JOIN courseDiscussions on discussions.dID = courseDiscussions.discussionID WHERE courseDiscussions.courseID = :cID");
    $last = $pdo->prepare("SELECT logTime from logs WHERE logAction = 'view' AND logUserID = :user AND logPageID = :dID ORDER BY logTime DESC LIMIT 1");
    $posts = $pdo->prepare("SELECT postAuthorID, postMessage, postTime, users.firstName, postID, postType FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.postAuthorID = users.userID WHERE postID IN (SELECT logActionID FROM logs INNER JOIN discussionPosts ON discussionPosts.postID = logs.logActionID WHERE logs.logAction = 'addPost' AND logs.logTime > :lastView AND logs.logPageID = :dID)");
    while($row = $courses->fetch()){
        $cID = $row['courseID'];
        if(!$discs->execute(array(':cID'=>$cID)))
            return -1;
        while($d_row = $discs->fetch()){
            $dID = $d_row['dID'];
            //find out when the user last visited this disucssion
            $last->execute(array(':user'=>$user,':dID'=>$dID));
            $lastView = $last->fetch();
            $lastView = $lastView['logTime'];
            if(empty($lastView)){
                $lastView = $d_row['courseDiscussionTime'];                 
            }
            $posts->execute(array(':lastView'=>$lastView,':dID'=>$dID));
            while($p_row = $posts->fetch()){
                $path = "/discussion.php?c=".$cID."&d=".$dID."&p=".$p_row['postID'];
                array_push($actions, array("action" => 'post',"actionTime" =>$p_row['postTime'], "actionType" =>$p_row['postType'], "context" =>'discussion', "contextLabel" =>$d_row['dTitle'] ,"contextID" =>$dID, "agentLabel" => $p_row['firstName'], "agentID" =>$p_row['postAuthorID'], "content" =>substr($p_row['postMessage'],0,120), "actionPath" =>$path)); 
            }
        }
    }
    usort($actions, function($a,$b){
        return strtotime($b['actionTime']) - strtotime($a['actionTime']);
    });
    $actions = array_slice($actions,0,$length);

    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: You have multiple nested query/fetch loops which could possibly be accomplished with a single join query. One of the queries is likely the source of slow performance, especially since they're being executed in a loop.

Comment: Like Michael said, your `$courses` results are creating a multiplier effect. Instead of running all those queries individually, you should combine them and limit the results before your loop as much as possible.

Comment: I see, this is now looping through several times. I'll work on improving the query. Thanks!